# Configuring Custom Login Realm and Module on a Standalone Glassfish through DAS

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a working custom login realm (provided by a third-party) for Glassfish 3.1.1. I've successfully deployed and configured it through the admin console on a single Glassfish instance on my workstation by dropping the loginmodule jar into domains/domainname/lib folder. Works with the webapp and everything.

Now I'm trying to deploy the application onto a bit more complicated setup. Consider the following three servers:

```
DAS: Admin server instance with domain

FRONT1: Standalone node instance configured through DAS

SERVICE1: Standalone node instance configured through DAS
```

I have dropped the loginmodule jar into nodes/front1/lib folder (on FRONT1 server). I have separate Configurations for each instance on DAS named front1_config and service1_config. I'm trying to add a new Realm with admin console through Configurations -> front1_config -> Security -> Realms but I get the following error:

Web:

```
Creation of Authrealm custom-realm failed. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The DAS server log:

```
[#|2011-11-01T14:22:18.258+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'https://localhost:4848/management/domain/configs/config/front1-config/security-service/auth-realm'; attrs = '{classname=com.mycompany.loginmodule.MyLoginRealm, name=custom-card, target=front1-config, property=}'|#]
```

I suspect this might be a problem with the placement of loginmodule.jar. Or maybe the NullPointerException is thrown from the loginmodule itself? I have tried numerous approaches, even copying the jar into glassfish/lib on both FRONT1 and DAS but nothing seems to work.

I'm at my wit's end here.

EDIT: I found out a bit more. I'd appeared to have copied the loginmodule jar also to the DAS servers domain/lib. When I removed the loginmodule jar from there, the NullpointerException did not appear and I just get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Creation of Authrealm custom-realm failed.
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.BadRealmException:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.mycompany.loginmodule.MyLoginRealm not found by org.glassfish.security [117]
```

Comment: I actually got somewhere with this. I haven't had the possibility to confirm it works. What I did was copy-paste realm config from the working single-domain domain.xml to the FRONT1 node's domain.xml config and then copied the loginmodule jar to DAS domain's lib. After this the FRONT1 log shows that the realm was configured ok. I will try to confirm it works later and submit the info. Unfortunately I don't know what caused the initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish 3.x has the default functionality to replicate some (if not all?) configuration from the DAS server's domain/domainname/ folder to the node servers. I added the loginmodule jar and login.conf configurations to the DAS server's domain/domainname/lib and domain/domainname/config and after restarting the FRONT1 instance from DAS admin console, the correct loginmodule jar and the login.conf were uploaded to the instance server. Now the loginmodule works as intended.

I'm still not sure if this is the absolute correct or the most secure way to achieve this in this kind of setting, but it seems to work.